# Issue adding request headers for Django Tests

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I need to add a header to a request in a Django test. I have browsed a few pages on both Stack Overflow and elsewhere, following various suggestions. I can add the headers to PUTs and GETs successfully, but having an issue with POSTs. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

For PUT and GET I have used the following [passing successfully]:

```
resp = self.client.put(resource_url, res_params, **{'HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_CERT': self.client_cert})
```

For POST, I tried the same thing but am receiving the error: 
"'str' object has no attribute 'items'"

I have tried the following:

```
resp = self.client.post(resource_url, res_params, **{'HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_CERT': self.client_cert})

resp = self.client.post(resource_url, res_params, HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_CERT=self.client_cert)

resp = self.client.post(resource_url, res_params, HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_CERT='1234567890')
```

Comment: code looks correct ...

Comment: add keyword as: `headers=your_dict_headers`

Comment: thanks for the quick responses! :) 

do you mean like below? I have tried this but get the same error message unfortunately; 'str' object has no attribute 'items'. The traceback suggests post doesnt take such arguments but I can't imagine I can do it for PUT and GET, but not POST?!

    resp = self.client.post(resource_url, res_params, headers={'HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_CERT': self.client_cert})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anybody that finds themselves looking at this page with a similar issue, I was able to get this working with the following:

```
resp = self.client.post(resource_url, data=res_params, content_type='application/json', HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_CERT=self.client_cert)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to add the prefix `HTTP_` to your header name

```
resp = self.client.post(resource_url,  HTTP_YOUR_CUSTOM_HEADER="your value")
```